# I need to delete my Ubuntu partitions on my laptop dual booting windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I need to delete my Ubuntu partitions but I can't tell which are the right ones on disk management. Any help would be much appreciated.
 [disk management screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drrhw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Windows actually cannot identify a linux type partition (ext4/ext3/swap).

Fire up an ubuntu installation iso [(Download)](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). You can burn this iso to a cd, or use  [Startup disk creator](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) to create a bootable usb.

After launching the iso, hit the windows button (super on linux, command button on Macs) and search for "gparted". click it. (this can also be done by hitting

`CTRL-ALT-t` and typing `sudo gparted`.)
**Be carefull When using gparted!** This application can do some real damage to your drive if not used properly.

In gparted, use this button on the top right corner:

[image: gparted button]

to find your drive that has ubuntu on it.
Ubuntu will have an ext4 partition. (Dark blue) Additionally, linux also has something called swap (orange). You may delete that as well.

Don't forget to hit the green check when you wish to apply the changes.

Note:

Your windows partition is called NTFS. **Do not delete this partition**

You can now go on to resize your windows partition, by right clicking 
it.

Answer (score 0):

INeedHelpA's answer is basically correct (although ext4fs is simply the default filesystem for Ubuntu; it *might* be installed using some other filesystem). There are, though, two more issues....

- It's imperative that you positively identify *every* partition on the disk as belonging to Windows, Ubuntu, or both. Your [EFI System Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) (ESP; probably `/dev/sda2` in Ubuntu, given your Windows screen shot) is shared, but every other partition probably belongs to just one OS. (An exception might be if you created a separate partition for shared data.) A default Ubuntu installation uses two partitions, one for the OS and your personal files and another for swap space; however, you might have created additional partitions. To fully recover your disk space, you should delete *all* the Ubuntu partitions and then either create new NTFS partition(s) in their place or resize your NTFS partitions; however, if you mistakenly delete any Windows partition, or the ESP, the computer may misbehave or even become unusable.
- Ubuntu configures the computer to boot through GRUB, which is installed on the ESP; but Ubuntu's GRUB configuration relies on files in the Ubuntu `/boot` directory. Thus, when you delete the Ubuntu partitions, GRUB will remain in control of the boot process but will misbehave. The result is that the computer will hang at a `grub>` prompt at boot time. To correct this problem, you can use the [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) program in Windows or `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu to alter the boot order, setting Windows at the top of the boot list. Alternatively, you can delete the Ubuntu boot loader from the ESP. (It normally lives in `EFI/ubuntu` on the ESP.) If you forget to do this and wind up looking at a `grub>` prompt, you may be able to use your computer's built-in boot manager to boot to Windows. How to access this tool varies from one computer to another, but it's usually Esc, Enter, or a function key as the computer starts up. (You may have used this tool to select the Ubuntu installation medium.)